# Openapi schema incorrect

Tags: angular, openapi, openapi-generator

I made a openapi spec and we use it to generate code BE and FE. It works fine but gives me a warning about the type of my schema. It defaults then to 'object' which is why it works, but that is not a good solution.

Please have a look at the code and help me see something (obvious) that I am missing here. Thx.
The error:

```
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.TypeScriptAngularClientCodegen - generating code for Angular 11.0.0 ...
[main] INFO  o.o.c.l.TypeScriptAngularClientCodegen -   (you can select the angular version by setting the additionalProperty ngVersion)
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] INFO  o.o.codegen.TemplateManager - writing file /home/chai/Nextcloud/Documents/nerdspul/werkspul/dev-division/mosar/src/frontend/mosar-frontend/./build/openapi/model/./flashcard.ts
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - #components/schemas/Flashcard is not defined
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - #components/schemas/Flashcard is not defined
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Error obtaining the datatype from ref:#components/schemas/Flashcard. Default to 'object'
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - #components/schemas/Flashcard is not defined
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Error obtaining the datatype from ref:#components/schemas/Flashcard. Default to 'object'
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - #components/schemas/Flashcard is not defined
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Error obtaining the datatype from ref:#components/schemas/Flashcard. Default to 'object'
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - #components/schemas/Flashcard is not defined
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Error obtaining the datatype from ref:#components/schemas/Flashcard. Default to 'object'
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.utils.ModelUtils - Failed to get the schema name: #components/schemas/Flashcard
```

And the code:

```
openapi: '3.0.0'
servers:
  # - url: http://localhost:8080/api
  # mockapi.io
  - url: https://6071a9e850aaea0017284e9d.mockapi.io/api

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Flashcard API
paths:
  /flashcard/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
        - FlashcardApi
      description: Returns a single flashcard by id.
      operationId: getFlashcard
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Flashcard'
        404:
          description: Flashcard does not exist.
        500:
          description: A server error occurred.
  /flashcard:
    post:
      tags:
        - FlashcardApi
      description: Saves a single flashcard in the db.
      operationId: createFlashcard
      requestBody:
        description: Json object to create a flashcard
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#components/schemas/Flashcard'

      responses:
        200:
          description: A flashcard.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Flashcard'
        404:
          description: Flashcard does not exist.
        500:
          description: A server error occurred.

components:
  schemas:
    Flashcard:
      type: object
      properties:
        term:
          type: string
        explanation:
          type: string
        id:
          type: string
        createDate:
          type: string
        changeDate:
          type: string
        createdBy:
          type: string
        changedBy:
          type: string
      required:
        - term
        - explanation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change: `$ref: '#components/schemas/Flashcard'`
to: `$ref: '#/components/schemas/Flashcard'` (you missed the /)

Also add this into the first get (`/flashcard/{id}:`)
to return the correct type:

```
 responses:
   200:
     description: flash card
       content:
         application/json:
           schema:
             $ref: '#/components/schemas/Flashcard'
```

Comment: Wow, very easy, and easily overlooked apparently. Thank you !

Comment: I rewrote what you had and still didn't notice it, had to check line-by-line :D